# Relay host based on destination MX record

Tags: postfix

I wish to set up Postfix to use an external relay depending on the destination hostname, ie:

- If destination hostname is *.outlook.com, use relay some_smtp.example.com
- If any other destination hostname, use local relay

**What I mean by destination hostname is the hostname obtained from MX record.** If the recipient domain has MX record `microsoft-com.mail.protection.outlook.com`, then use a different relay

I know it is possible to specify a relay depending on the sender address (using `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps`), but it's impractical in my situation.

The goal is to use a different relay for finicky destination hosts: maybe Mandrill, or another Postfix installation.

Answer (score 7):

You can setup a transport map to selectively choose mails with `@outlook.com` as destination address and relay them via `some_smtp.example.com` as shown below.

Add the entry below to `/etc/postfix/transport`

```
outlook.com smtp:[some_smtp.example.com]
```

Add the entry below to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

Restart postfix after the following command

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/transport
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Please see my edit about "destination hostname". Should have been more specific.

Answer (score 7):

[Arul's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/663435/218590) was perfect for transport based on recipient domain. However, bencaue you refer to  MX record hostname instead recipient domain, the answer was non-applicable.

One solution is using `check_recipient_mx_access`. Snippet from [official docs](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_recipient_mx_access)

> **check_recipient_mx_access *type:table***
>
> > Search the **specified access(5) database for the MX hosts for the RCPT TO domain**, and execute the corresponding action. Note: a result of "OK" is not allowed for safety reasons. Instead, use DUNNO in order to exclude specific hosts from blacklists. This feature is available in Postfix 2.1 and later.

For your case, just put `check_recipient_mx_access hash:/etc/postfix/finickydestination` in appropriate place `smtpd_*_restriction`. In that file put the hostname

```
# /etc/postfix/finickydestination
.outlook.com FILTER smtp:[some_smtp.example.com]
```

Don't forget to postmap the file and execute postfix reload.

Reference(s):

- [Postfix patch announcement](http://archives.neohapsis.com/archives/postfix/2003-09/1616.html) regarding [VeriSign site finder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_Finder)
- [Another people which has same problem](http://marc.info/?l=postfix-users&m=121920465018833&w=2)

Comment: This of course is not working (unfortunately). Put in the smtpd_recipient_restriction, results in:
postfix/smtpd: warning: do not specify lookup tables inside SMTPD access maps
postfix/smtpd: warning: define a restriction class and specify its name instead.

Answer (score 2):

As @user221326 (i don't have enough rep to comment myself) pointed out @masegaloeh answer will **NOT** work as `check_recipient_mx_access` expects a **access table** with a `ACTION`

More info in the [man page](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html)

The action you want is `FILTER` so something like

```
.outlook.com FILTER smtp:[some_smtp.example.com]
```

Note if you have multiple `FILTER` only the last will fire so ensure this comes after everything else.

Furthermore `.outlook.com` will only catch sub/super domains (e.g. whatever.protection.outlook.com) if `smtpd_access_maps` is **NOT** in `parent_domain_matches_subdomains`, otherwise you want `outlook.com` (no leading dot)

Lastly keep in mind that this action applies to the **whole message** as soon as one recipients MX matches the domain, which should be a non-issue as long as your defined target isn't a MDA.

Cheers

Comment: This change is now propagated to the original @masegaloeh answer.

Answer (score 1):

**2021 Update**

I did try all this, but it did not seems to work. The solution I present was "assembled" from several sources.

---

in `main.cf` you need to add following:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions   =
        check_recipient_mx_access   pcre:/etc/postfix/mxtransport
```

then you do `/etc/postfix/mxtransport` as "usual":

```
/google\.com$/              FILTER smtp:[smtp.com]:25
/googlemail\.com$/          FILTER smtp:[smtp.com]:25
/protection\.outlook\.com$/ FILTER smtp:[smtp.com]:25

/spamexperts\.com$/         FILTER smtp:[smtp.com]:25
/spamexperts\.net$/         FILTER smtp:[smtp.com]:25
/spamexperts\.eu$/          FILTER smtp:[smtp.com]:25
```

This assures, that emails sent to google / outlook / spamexperts clients (for example something@google.com, something@hotmail.com, something@tui.de etc), will go via third party route (smtp.com) instead via local IP.

---

I am still using Postfix 2.10.1 (CentOS 7)

Comment: If it saves others the head scratching - the PCRE dictionary isn't installed out of the box with Ubuntu, but can be grabbed with sudo apt install postfix-pcre

Answer (score 0):

As commented above: "For your case, just put check_recipient_mx_access hash:/etc/postfix/finickydestination in appropriate place smtpd_*_restriction. In that file put the hostname"

smtpd_sender_restrictions is not the appropriate place, as at the point in the smtp transaction, postfix does not know who the receiver is.

Also if you had any more FILTER statements, such as spam/virus scanning, it would override that FILTER statement, if they happened after smtpd_sender_restrictions.