# postfix relayhost based on the mail recipient

Tags: postfix

Is it possible to send mail on a postfix server using a different relayhost based on the mail recipient?

For example: the mails destined for hotmail use a relayhost and the recipients with another destination other relayhost.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that with transport_maps. See my answer to a similar question here that explains how to setup transport_maps.

[Relay host based on destination MX record](https://serverfault.com/questions/663418/relay-host-based-on-destination-mx-record/663435#663435)