# Configure smtp relay for a domain

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, iredmail

I have a mail server on debian iredmail/dovecot/postfix everything works good except one domaine that's not receiving my emails because we are blacklisted somewhere and i can't find anyway to fix this.

so the solution i see is to handle emails we are sending to that domain using another smtp server (as relay).

Ihave the appropriate server for this but i don't know how to do it yet. i checked google and fould some articles but all explain how to use a relay to send all emails not for a specific domaine only.

In brief: i want all emails sent to (thisomain.com) served and sent by my relay server (smtp.mysecondmailserver.com).

Any idea how to do this?

Thakns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with transport_maps. See my answer to a similar question here that explains how to setup transport_maps.

[Relay host based on destination MX record](https://serverfault.com/questions/663418/relay-host-based-on-destination-mx-record/663435#663435)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.
how to add hash:/etc/postfix/transport ? in may case i have this :
transport_maps =
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf
    proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf